# can I force usage of specific tablespace for singe pg_restore task?

Tags: postgresql

is there some clever way to force usage of specific tablespace for pg_restore task in situation when I need to run independently in parallel several pg_restore tasks and I would need to direct some of them into tablespace on SSD and others into specific tablespaces on other standard disks?

We got this use case - daily during the night we need to copy daily partitions into new warehouse database. Standard pg_dump / pg_restore is currently used (logical replication is currently not possible for internal policy reasons although it would be highly desirable).

More pg_restore tasks run in parallel on target database and I would need to set specific target tablespace for specific task - therefore global "default_tablespace" setting does not help. I also cannot reconfigure source database to have proper tablespace directly in dump not to mention that with growth of warehouse DB I would need to change target tablespaces from time to time.

Originally I thought PG env var "PGTARGETSESSIONATTRS" could maybe help me to set "default_tablespace" for specific session of pg_restore but looks like this var cannot do it.

Databases are PG 10 (source) and PG 11 (target).

Comment: You could create the tables first, adjust their tablespaces and then run `pg_restore` with the `--data-only` option.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right - I did not think about it... thanks, I will test it

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment from @a_horse_with_no_name I tested this sequence of commands which does what I need:

- pg_dump -U user1 -v -F c --no-tablespaces -t schema.table database1 -f exportfile
- pg_restore -U user2 -v --no-tablespace -d database2  --schema-only -c exportfile
- psql -U user2 -d database2 -c "alter table schema.table set tablespace xxxx"
- pg_restore -U  user2 -v --no-tablespace -d database2 --data-only exportfile

Comment: You will also need an ALTER INDEX command to also move indexes to the new tablespace like this:
psql -U user2 -d database2 -c "alter index schema.table_foo_index set tablespace xxxx"